# How to get value of variable at the end of test execution in python pytest

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I am using pytest framework and trying to integrate test case with Testrail.
I need to do mapping of test case with test case IDs in testrail.

Consider below scenario where there are 2 test cases.

```
    def test_login1():
     test_case_id= 10
    
    def test_login2():
     test_case_id= 20
```

I need variable (test_case_id), once each and every test case executed. "test_case_id" is basically testcase ID in testrail. At the end of testcase execution, I am checking testcase result (passed or failed) and integrating with testrail using TC Id. Test case ID will be passed from Testcase and in conftest.py.

I have 2 hooks created in conftest file.

```
    @pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
    def pytest_runtest_makereport(item):
        """
        This function will be executed after execution of each and every test case.
        Results dictionary will contain details of executed TC
        """
        outcome = yield
        result = outcome.get_result()
    
        if result.when == 'call':
            item.session.results[item] = result
    
       def pytest_sessionfinish(session):
        """
        This function will be execution post execution of all test cases
        """
        passed_amount = sum(1 for result in session.results.values() if result.passed)
        failed_amount = sum(1 for result in session.results.values() if result.failed)
        logger.info('**** Test Summary ****')
        logger.info(f'Passed Test Cases Count -> {passed_amount}')
        logger.info(f'Failed Test Cases Count -> {failed_amount}')
```

At the end of execution of these 2 hooks, I am expecting output in list or dictionary containing

```
<test_case_id: <tc_result> eg. (10: Passed and 20: Failed) or ( 10:True and 20:False)
```

Comment: What happens when run in it's current state?  are you able to collect the results of each test okay, and all you need is the test_id variable to map the data?

Comment: Yes. Test case results are captured correctly. I just need TC case ID which will be different for each and every TC

Comment: Since you have already implemented your own hooks you should check out this  it might fit your needs... https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/writing_hook_functions.html#storing-data-on-items-across-hook-functions

Comment: Thanks. What other options are there in case I want to re-write hooks? I am new to python/pytest.